# How do I save a file in a library location other than the default

Tags: windows-7, windows-libraries

Win7 libraries have a default folder location, but there are times I want to save to a different one (eg My Documents vs Shared Documents) but I can't find any way to specify any of the other locations from the file-save dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the list of libraries in the dialog's left side pane, expand your library. The folders that are included in your library will be shown. Click on the folder that you wish to save to. The file will now be saved in that location.

Edit: The blue arrow shows where to click

[image]

Edit: In the case of the old save/open dialogs, you go into your library, right click on the folder that you want to save in, and select "Open Folder Location".

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to be clicking in again?  I can target sub folders of the ones in the library, but I can't select the folders I made into the library itself.   eg if my library consists of My Documents and Shared Documents I can expand the library and click on Shared Documents\Sub Folder, but if the default is My Documents, I don't have any way to save directly in the Shared Documents folder.

Comment: I added a picture to show you where to click. Here Apple, Banana, Orange are folders included in the library Test. Apple is the default. Expanding Test, and clicking on Banana where the arrow indicates, selects Banana as the save location.

Comment: That's interesting.  I get that save as dialog in FF/IE, but in Opera (my normal browser), acrobat reader, and textpad I get a different one that has 32x32 icons in the sidebar instead of the treeview.  I've never understood why MS provided more than one file dialog layout in the first place nor why in none of the OS updates since doing that have they changed it so all the options work the same way.

Comment: Added info about the old-style dialogs for you